# Por quê nada do meu aplicativo React é exibido?

Tags: react

Tenho um aplicativo React com o seguinte código no App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            firstNumber : 0,
            secondNumber : 0,
            result : 0
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event){
        const {name,value} = event.target;
        this.setState({
            [name] : value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Choose your first number"
                        name="firstNumber"
                        value={this.state.firstNumber}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Choose your second number"
                        name="secondNumber"
                        value={this.state.secondNumber}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <h1>Result : {this.state.result}</h1>
                </label>
                <h1>{this.state.firstNumber}</h1>
                <h1>{this.state.secondNumber}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default 'App';
```

---

E no index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Gostaria de saber porque nada é exibido quando executo meu `yarn start`.

Comment: Aqui `export default 'App';` deveria ser `export default App;`, você está tentando exportar uma string e não a variável que é o seu componente

Comment: como estar seu package.json? olhe start o que ta acontecendo la

Comment: Seu código de exemplo funcionando https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-azsnge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `export default` você coloca o Component criado que no caso é o `App` da seguinte forma:

```
export default App;
```

e além disso se quiser algo dinâmico na hora da digitação dos números já ir calculando o resultado após a mudança no estado deve ser criado um função que é executado após a atualização do estado da seguinte forma:

```
this.setState({
    [name] : value
}, () => { // função que é executado após atualizar o valor do estado
  const firstNumber = parseInt( this.state.firstNumber);
  const secondNumber = parseInt(this.state.secondNumber);
  this.setState({
    result: firstNumber + secondNumber
  });
});
```

E logo abaixo o exemplo completo:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            firstNumber : 0,
            secondNumber : 0,
            result : 0
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event){
        const {name,value} = event.target;
        this.setState({
            [name] : value
        }, () => {
          const firstNumber = parseInt( this.state.firstNumber);
          const secondNumber = parseInt(this.state.secondNumber);
          this.setState({
            result: firstNumber + secondNumber
          });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Choose your first number"
                        name="firstNumber"
                        value={this.state.firstNumber}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Choose your second number"
                        name="secondNumber"
                        value={this.state.secondNumber}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <h1>Result : {this.state.result}</h1>
                </label>
                <h1>{this.state.firstNumber}</h1>
                <h1>{this.state.secondNumber}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

*Vale muito lembrar que os dados digitados terão que ser números do tipo inteiro qualquer outra digitação diferente o código também precisa ser refatorado, mas, o problema inicial é porque no `export` configurou um texto e não o componente.*

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado!